# Spark (Scala): Attribute name contains invalid character

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to write DataFrame to HDFS, I faced with the following issue:

```
  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name " "someName1"" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;
```

The source for DataFrame is a csv-file:

```
       "value_hash", "someName1"
       79000000000, name1
       79000000000, name2
```

This csv read by:

```
    val dataFrame = SparkSession.read.option("header", "true").csv(path)
```

Then I select and cast types for this dataFrame:

```
   def castColumn(colName: String, colType: String): Column = col(colName).cast(DataType.fromJson(colType))

val featureColumns: Seq[(PathString, String)] = dataFrame.columns.tail.map(f=>(f, "\"string\"")).toSeq

val columns = (schema ++ featureColumns).
  map { case (colName, colType) => castColumn(colName, colType) }
dataFrame.select(columns.toSeq: _*)
```

where schema has type: Map[String, String] and has a default value  Map("value_hash" -> ""string"")

In this code I prepend featureColumns-schema to default schema (as I didn't know full source-schema - it created dynamically after read csv from hdfs).

Then I'm trying to write this DataFrame in hdfs-path:

```
  dataFrame
      .repartition(1)
      .write
      .parquet(outputPath)
```

Following recommendation in error-message, I tried to use alias for each column so:

```
 filteredRemove.columns.foreach{
  ca=>filteredRemove.select(col(ca).alias(ca)))
}
```

and so:

```
filteredRemove.columns.foreach{
  ca=>filteredRemove.select(col(ca).alias(ca)).show()
}
```

But result was the same: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException...

Notices the whitespace and quotation marks in " "someName1"", I also tried to clear alias from this:

```
 filteredRemove.columns.foreach{
  ca=>filteredRemove.select(col(ca).alias(ca.trim.substring(0,ca.length-1))).show()
}
```

But without any result. I still faces with the exception, which showed above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like ```"someName1"``` has a leading space.

Comment: I tried remove this space by String.trim(). But without result. I showed this attempt in my post

Comment: Please add a reproducible code with a sample

Comment: David, I updated question with sample

Comment: The post is a mess and there is code missing. Please edit it so it will reflect a coherent flow that yields an exception (the original one, note as a result of the other attempts)

Comment: David, I update my question with full workflow

Comment: Not quite what I meant. See my answer which include the issue generation and the solution. Give me a minute and I'll also demonstrate renaming of suck a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option) to true, to eliminate the issue already during the load

**Original code**

```
val df_original = spark.read.option("header",true).csv(path)
```

---

```
println((for(c <- df_original.columns) yield s"`$c`").mkString(","))

`value_hash`,` "someName1"`
```

**Ways for renaming the column after the load**

```
val df_renamed_1 = df_original.withColumnRenamed(" \"someName1\"", "someName1")
```

---

```
println((for(c <- df_renamed_1.columns) yield s"`$c`").mkString(","))

`value_hash`,`someName1`
```

---

```
val df_renamed_2 = df_original.withColumnRenamed(""" "someName1"""", "someName1")
```

---

```
println((for(c <- df_renamed_2.columns) yield s"`$c`").mkString(","))

`value_hash`,`someName1`
```

**A ways to avoid the issue during the load (include `option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace",true)`)**

```
val df_fixed = spark.read.option("header",true).option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace",true).csv(path)
```

---

```
println((for(c <- df_fixed.columns) yield s"`$c`").mkString(","))

`value_hash`,`someName1`
```

Comment: I will try it. In 10 minutes I will tell you the result